# AddPicture function

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am having issues with the AddPicture function in WORD-VBA. I have searched the web and tried examples I found but they all failed in some regard.  I would appreciate some help. I am stumped. I suspect I am not defining something properly.

Here is my code:

```
Function FnImageInsert(strCompleteImagePath)

   Dim objWord

   Dim objDoc

   Dim objSelection

   Dim Shp As shape

   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\test\testimage.docx")

   objWord.Visible = True

' Selection Class
   Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

   objSelection.TypeText (vbCrLf & "One Picture will be inserted here...." & vbCrLf)

'
'Having a problem below... I get Object required error (424)
'
   Set Shp = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=strCompleteImagePath, SaveWithDocument:=True).ConvertToShape
'
'
'

   Close objSelection

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I have commented your code below and hope this will help.

```
Function FnImageInsert(strCompleteImagePath)

    ' This code would be correct if you run Word from Excel
    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim objSelection As Word.Object
    ' If you run this code from Word you don't need to declare
    ' the application and the objects don't need to specify Word
'    Dim objDoc As Document
'    Dim objSelection As Object
    Dim Shp As Shape

    ' omit this object if you run this code from within Word
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\test\testimage.docx")

    ' it's the window you can make visible, not the application
    ' the application is always invisible
'    objWord.Visible = True

'  Selection Class: This looks like a little code from VB (this is VBA)

    ' I don't know if this actually works. I never saw this before.
    ' in fact, there is one "Selection" in Word which is the currently
    ' selected range in the ActiveDocument
    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
    ' However, since you already have the 'Selection' object, why do you need
    ' a copy of it in 'objSelection'?

    ' the parentheses are superfluous here:
    objSelection.TypeText (vbCrLf & "One Picture will be inserted here...." & vbCrLf)

    ' Having a problem below... I get Object required error (424)
    ' Of course: Shp is a Shape (see the Dim statement)
    ' You are adding an InlineShape and assigning it to Shp, which cuses the error
    Set Shp = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=strCompleteImagePath, SaveWithDocument:=True).ConvertToShape
    ' If you wish to convert the Inlineshape to Shape, you should do this
    ' by setting the WrapText property after creation.
    ' But why not create a shape rightaway, if you don't want an InlineShape?

    ' You can't "Close" the Selection object
    ' In fact, there always is a selection while the document is open
    ' and all you can do is move it or dete4rmine its size.
'    Close objSelection
End Function
```

Comment: I used your code and it failed at the compile stage at

Comment: "Dim objWord As Word.Application".. saying user defined type not assigned.

Comment: I am using VBA from within Excel  The original issue is the AddPicture function.. the rest works fine... could you please comment on that function.  I noticed you mentioned Shp is a Shape.. according to MSDN, inlineShapes returns a collections of Shapes... so how to I change the assignment of Shp to correct the error?

Comment: It's the declaration `Dim Shp As Shape` which prevents an InlineShape being assigned to that variable. Declare Shp as InlineShape. Then remove the `ConvertToShape` from `AddPicture` line. Once you have the InlineShape object safely assigned to the Shp variable you can start modifying it. However, you would need to introduce another variable of Shape type to which you can then assign the converted InlineShape. You might try declaring `Dim Shp As Object`, and that might permit you to switch types.